# Example link Required for Uses of acegisecurity framework with spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am currently developing my project using Spring, Sutruts2 & Hibernate. Now i want to apply acegi security for authentication & authrization purpose.

But, i m totally new with acegi, so i want to use acegisecurity framework with spring configuration.

If anyone have link for an simple example of acegi with spring, struts2 & hibernate then please provide me it.

Thanx in advance.....

Comment: Hi Nirmal - update my answer with a more recent tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using acegi or spring security? Acegi has been repackaged (and simplified with respect to configuration) to become spring security, as described on the [homepage](http://www.acegisecurity.org/)

> Acegi Security is now Spring Security, the official security project of the Spring Portfolio. If you are planning a new project, we'd recommend you consider using Spring Security. Acegi Security 1.0.7 will be the last non-critical release of the 1.0.x series.

See also Ben Alex's [blog](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/12/06/whats-new-in-spring-security-2/)

Update: A spring security tutorial is available [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html)

Comment: thanx buddy, but i am little confused with the example given with default download named as "acegi-security-samples-tutorial-1.0.7" have some other configuration than the Ben Alex's blog. What actually alex's blog suggest in spring configuration file ?

Comment: When they moved from Acegi Security to Spring-Security the Spring guys changed the way the XML config worked, made the basic setup more automatic.  I would suggest using Spring Security rather then the older Acegi libraries, and ignore links you find to Acegi tutorials because they will confuse the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [tutorial sample](http://www.acegisecurity.org/suggested.html) available as part of the acegi distribution.